# LightGBM windows installation issue - cmake - does not support platform specification

Tags: cmake, windows-10, lightgbm

I am trying to install LightGBM in windows 10 using cmake.

I am following the process given on this [link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#windows)

on this command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 ..
```

it gives the error saying

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (PROJECT):

  Generator

NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/meetp/LightGBM/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I'm new to this, since I've never used cmake before.

can someone give me some insights about what parameter i need to add in cmake command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform specification is mainly used for Visual Studio generator. Sometimes, CMake uses this generator by default. In other cases, you need to specify generator **explicitly**, with `-G` option:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 ..
```

(Make sure that generator corresponds to the Visual Studio which you actually have. See [list of Visual Studio generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators) supported by CMake.)